# Foundation for Apps: off-canvas menu hovers the frame instead of sliding with it

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-apps

```
<body zf-close-all>

<div>
<!-- <zf-panel id="dolly-the-menu" position="left" class="primary offcanvasmenu"> -->
    <zf-offcanvas id="offcanvasMenu" position="left" class="primary offcanvasmenu">

    <!-- <a href="#" zf-close="" class="close-button">x</a> -->
        <strong class="menu-logo" style="color: white;">Soccer Scout</strong>

        <ul class="menu-bar condense vertical">
            <li><a ui-sref="home"  ui-sref-active-eq="menu-item-is-active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="soccerscout"  ui-sref-active-eq="menu-item-is-active">What is Soccer Scout?</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="forplayers"  ui-sref-active-eq="menu-item-is-active">For Players</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="forintermediaries"  ui-sref-active-eq="menu-item-is-active">For Intermediaries</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="forclubs"  ui-sref-active-eq="menu-item-is-active">For Clubs</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="foracademies"  ui-sref-active-eq="menu-item-is-active">For Academies</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="trials">Trials</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="blog">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="pricing">Pricing</a></li>

        </ul>
    </zf-offcanvas>
<!-- </zf-panel> -->
</div>


<div class="grid-frame vertical">

    <div class="grid-content shrink" style="padding: 0;">
        <div ng-include="" src="'partials/nav.html'"></div>
    </div>
    <div ui-view class="grid-content">
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div ng-class="['ui-animation']" ui-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have placed the `zf-offcanvas` block before `grid-frame` as mentioned in the docs. But, the off canvas menu hovers the site content instead of pushing it aside.

So how can I get the off-canvas menu working without hovering the site content.

[image: Off-canvas disabled]

---

Img2:

[image: offcanvas enabled]